# Interrupt the "say" process from a mac launched in java

Tags: java, macos, text-to-speech

At some point, my java code launches the "say" command of the Mac OS by a simple line like:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("say -v Victoria -f /Users/user/Desktop/folder1/example.txt");`

But now, if a new "say" command is launched, obviously there are two voices speaking at the same time. My question is about interrupting the first voice (process) inside my code. I know how to do it in the terminal, but not from the code.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'I know how to do it in the terminal'? How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec command returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object. You can use [destroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) method to kill the process.